# Pulp Scientist Body slots

Tags: d20-modern, d20-past

I'm building a Pulp Scientist in d20 Past, but having some trouble understanding the rules for Inventions (see my other [d20-past](/questions/tagged/d20-past) questions).

According to the Scientist Advanced Class (d20 Past, p84):

> Inventions tend to be bulky, weighing 10 pounds per level of discovery. Held, carried or worn inventions typically take up two body slots, chosen from the list in Chapter Ten of d20 Modern...

Where d20 Modern Chapter Ten (p374) says:

> Only so many magic items of a certain kind can be worn and be effective at the same time. The limits are:
>
> 1 headband, headset, hat, or helmet ; 1 pair of eyeglasses, contact lenses, sunglasses, or goggles ; 1 amulet, brooch, medallion, necklace, necktie, or scarab ; 1 suit of armor (archaic or modern) ; 1 robe, jacket, windbreaker, or coat ; 1 cloak, cape, poncho, sweater, or mantle ; 1 vest or shirt ; 1 pair of bracers or bracelets, or 1 watch ; 1 pair of gloves or gauntlets ; 1 pair of earrings ; 2 rings ; 1 belt ; 1 pair of boots, shoes, or sandals ; 6 tattoos

There is also a feat which uses a different list of body locations however:

> **Miniature Invention**
>
> You are adept at making compact, portable inventions.
>
> **Benefit:** Your inventions take up only one body slot, chosen
>   from the following list: head, eyes, back, torso, forearms, left
>   hand, right hand, belt, cape, legs, boots. The level of the discovery
>   used in the invention increases by 1. Miniature inventions
>   also weight only 5 pounds per level of the discovery.
>
> **Normal:** Inventions take up two body slots. For example, a
>   “mesmero-helm” incorporating the charm discovery might take
>   up both the eyes and head body slots. Inventions normally weih
>   10 pounds per level of the discovery.

I don't understand why this list is different from the list in Chapter Ten of d20 Modern.

#### Is the *body slot list* in the feat the one we should always use, or are we expected to use the feat list for this feat, but the list in chapter 10 for inventions which have not been miniaturised?

Comment: So, *in theory* you could have an invention that weighs 10+ pounds, and takes up *two tattoo slots*? That's a heavy couple of tattoos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You use the feat's list for miniaturized inventions, but the list in chapter 10 for inventions which have not been miniaturised.**

That's how feats and other things that modify the rules work: They change how the rules apply to things that fall under their criteria, but everything else that doesn't fall under that criteria remains unmodified.

The "normal" section doesn't change that, it simply serves as a reminder for how things would work if you do not have the feat or it does not apply, such as wearing a non-miniaturized invention.

Miniaturized Inventions weigh less and take a single body slot.
Non-miniaturized inventions remain heavy and bulky, using normal weight and taking two slots.

D20 Past isn't reinventing the wheel. It wants to be cool and refer to it as a "rotary locomotion support", but mechanically, nothing changes from the usual d20 rules.

Normally an item takes up only and exactly the slot[s] that it specifies that it does. However, bear in mind that there are a number of slots available to miniaturized items that are incompatible with items that normally occupy that slot.

- Head, Eyes, Belt, Cape, Boots: simply re-referencing existing slots. Does not allow you to wear a second item in the same slot.
- Back/Torso: MIGHT interfere with any of: suit of armor, robe, jacket, windbreaker, coat, vest or shirt.
- Forearms: bracers, bracelets, or watch.
- Left/Right Hand: cannot be worn with a pair of gloves or gauntlets.
- Legs: MIGHT interfere with a suit of armor.

As always, DM's discretion on what does or does not conflict.

Also note that due to the wording of the feat, "standard" slots are not usable for miniaturized inventions, and the miniaturized slot list is not available for standard inventions.

Comment: Thanks, but that begs the question, are Left/Right Ring the same slots as Left/Right Hand? What about Chest/Back and Vest/Amulet/Jacket. If I have a non miniaturised invention which takes up Left Ring and Watch slot, can it be worn at the same time as the miniaturised Left Hand slot. I think the answer is ultimately 'this wasn't really thought through, check with your GM'.

Comment: Looking at the Feat, I omitted the "***Normal:***" section, which might have some bearing on your answer, since now the feat (on p85) and the text on p84 appear to be in conflict.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, what I meant was "Is the Left Ring the same slot as Left Hand?  Is the Right Ring the same slot as Right Hand?" etc.

Comment: I guess what I'm taking away from this is that the body slots for the Miniature feat fall into two categories. The first consists of "head, eyes, forearms, belt, cape, boots" which have direct equivalents with the standard body slots. If you use these, they will prevent a standard invention using those slots. Then there are the slots unique to the Miniature feat, "back, torso, left hand, right hand, legs" which don't have directly equivalent slots, so *could* be used at the same time (just as you can wear a ring and gauntlets, or a coat over a vest). Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: I think we are moving into the realms of house rules now. Clearly if the slot is named the same, it is the same, but you can't argue that a slot is the same as a differently named slot. Some slots do coexist, if ring and gloves can coexist, I don't see why hand and gloves can't. Similarly vest, coat and armour all logically imply both torso and back, yet happily coexist with each other.

Comment: Yes, but it's the way it's worn, and the rules on interaction of items occupying the same slots. For instance, you may only benefit from either gloves or gauntlets at the same time, even though it is quite reasonable, physically, to wear them both. It's simply an extrapolation of existing rules. By the argument of "differently named" we should be able to wear a cloak, cape, poncho, sweater, ***AND*** mantle all at the same time, because they are all worn slightly differently. However the rules have already covered that the differences are too slight to distinguish them.

Comment: Don't be silly, "cloak, cape, poncho, sweater and mantle" are explicitly listed as the same slot. Left hand is not explicitly listed as the same as the gloves slot. That may be logical, but it's not what the rules say. Vest and Jacket are both covering the torso, but because the are in different slots, they can interact. It would be a GM call as to whether gloves and a specific hand slot can co-exist. For instance my hand slot miniature invention might be a something which can strap onto a hand already wearing a glove or gauntlet, just as a ring can be worn under that same glove or gauntlet.

Comment: Anyway, we should probably take this to [chat] if we want to discuss this further.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [tzxAzrael](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30162/tzxazrael)'s [excellent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/85093/1658) it seems clear to me now that there are three sets of body locations.

Firstly, there are body locations common to both the standard inventions and the Miniature inventions:

- head, eyes, forearms, belt, cape, boots

Using one of these body slots for a miniature invention prevents a normal invention being used in the same slot and vice versa.

Then there are body slots which are unique to Miniature inventions:

- back, torso, left hand, right hand, legs

Finally there are the body slots which are unique to normal inventions:

- amulet... ; armor ; jacket... ; vest... ; gloves... ; earrings ; 2 rings ; 6 tattoos

So if you don't have the Miniature Invention feat you have access to 14 body slots (excluding the 6 tattoo slots which I wouldn't expect to be usable for Inventions), but if you do have the feat you have access to an additional 5 body slots.

Comment: Yes and no; if you're already wearing gloves, for example, you can't wear a device on the left or right hand. A better split might be common slots, overlapping but different slots, and remaining standard slots. However, miniature inventions can only be placed into the miniature slots list, and standard inventions can only be placed in 2 standard slots.

Comment: Why not @tzxAzrael , you can wear a ring on each hand and a pair of gloves/gauntlets at the same time? Only a GM can make a ruling on this for their game, if there is not corroborating support for your assertion in the RAW.